# Can’t use checkbox inside ion-menu when using “contentId” for ion-menu

Tags: ionic-framework

It's been a while since I've been getting the following warnings from Ionic because of the structure of my menus:

> ```
> [DEPRECATED][ion-menu] Using the [main] attribute is deprecated, please use the "contentId" property instead:
> BEFORE:
>  <ion-menu>...</ion-menu>
>  <div main>...</div>
> AFTER:
>  <ion-menu contentId="main-content"></ion-menu>
>  <div id="main-content">...</div>
> ```

[Source of the error](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/6d6aba6d40d7bd72a0c16a3edb0538e632120678/core/src/components/menu/menu.tsx#L160)

So I decided to finally follow this advice and add a `contentId` attribute to my `<ion-menu>` and a `id` attribute to my `<ion-content>`, but now the checkboxes inside this menu don't work anymore. If I remove this "contentId" from the `<ion-menu>` and from the `<ion-content>` they return to work as expected.

Is there something more that needed to be changed? I read the source that I posted above, but could not find the reason for this situation. There is no error when the checkbox is clicked and the checkbox is never checked, it remains static indefinitely.

This error is not limited to the checkbox element, I can't use the ionic `click()` function too.

I tried with a very basic HTML structure too, but this situation persist.

I'm using a structure as it follows:

```html
...
<ion-content>
  <ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="firstContent">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-title>RandomTitle</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header> 
    <ion-content id="firstContent">
      <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>RandomName</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
</ion-content>
...
```

**Ionic V4**